# Calculate if $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|x^2y^2|}{|x^3|+|y^3|}$ exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to calculate if this limit exist:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\vert x^2y^2\vert}{\vert x^3\vert +\vert y^3\vert}$$

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: The first move would be testing along paths.

Answer (score 5):

by $AM-GM$ we get $$|x|^3+|y|^3\geq 2|xy|^{3/2}$$ from here we obtain
$$\frac{x^2y^2}{|x|^3+|y|^3}\le \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2y^2}{|xy|^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{2}|xy|^{1/2}\to0$$